# How do I check if a python boto3 paginator returned no results?

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, boto3, paginator

This should be an easy question, but just can't find the answer.

I am using a dynamodb paginator:

```
paginator = dynamoDbClient.get_paginator('query')
response_iterator = paginator.paginate(...)
```

I am looping through the results:

```
for response in response_iterator:
```

I expected the loop to not be executed when no results were found.  Unfortunately, it is and I can't figure out what to check for to indicate that no results were found.

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: `paginator.paginate` returns a `PageIterator`, which, as the name says, iterates over pages. Even if your query yields no results, you will always have at least one page (which in these cases, would be empty).

Answer (score 2):

Each page has a `KeyCount` key, which tells you how many S3 objects are contained in each page. If the first page from the paginator has a `KeyCount` of `0`, then you know it's empty.

Like this:

```py
paginator = client.get_paginator('list_objects_v2')
for page in paginator.paginate(Bucket='my-bucket', Prefix='my-prefix'):
  if page['KeyCount'] == 0:
    # The paginator is empty (and this should be the first page)
```

If you actually need to use the `KeyCount` for other purposes (e.g., 0 might mean you've processed a bunch of pages and then the last one is empty), you could do this:

```py
for i, page in enumerate(paginator.paginate(Bucket='my-bucket', Prefix='my-prefix')):
  if i == 0 and page['KeyCount'] == 0:
    # The paginator is empty
  else:
    # Paginator is not empty
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually I write my own pagination logic, something like the below:

```
while True:
    responseListPolicies = iam_client.list_policies(Marker=marker) if marker else iam_client.list_policies()
    truncatedListPolicies = responseListPolicies.get('IsTruncated')

    allPolicies = responseListPolicies.get('Policies')
    allPolicyArns += [policy.get('Arn') for policy in allPolicies]
    allPolicyNames += [policy.get('PolicyName') for policy in allPolicies]

    if not truncatedListPolicies:
        break
    marker = responseListPolicies.get('Marker')        
    print("Found truncated at marker " + marker)
```

However, I recently came across the `pagination` made available via boto3 and decided to play with it. That's where I stumbled upon a similar issue trying to fetch group policies.

Here's a snippet of what I tried:

```
paginator = iam_client.get_paginator('list_group_policies')
res = paginator.paginate(GroupName=name, PaginationConfig={'MaxItems': 100000})
listOfAllPolicyNames += res.build_full_result().get('PolicyNames')
```

And this threw an error like:

> An error occurred (NoSuchEntity) when calling the ListGroupPolicies operation: The group with name groupName cannot be found.

I started exploring it. What I did was try to see what are the methods made available on the *res* object. So a *dir(res)* gave something like this (partial results shown below):

```
 ...
 'build_full_result',
 'non_aggregate_part',
 'result_key_iters',
 'result_keys',
 'resume_token',
 'search']
```

I ended up looking at *result_keys* and it was something like this:

```
[{'type': 'field', 'children': [], 'value': 'PolicyNames'}]
```

I noticed that the `children` element was an empty list. So I tried the above pagination with another group name that I knew would certainly have some inline policies. And this time also the results were the same. So eventually, I realized that there may not be a directly available key that could be looked out for.

So finally had to resort back to the Exception handling way as below:

```
try:
    paginator = iam_client.get_paginator('list_group_policies')
    res = paginator.paginate(GroupName=name, PaginationConfig={'MaxItems': 100000})
    res.build_full_result()
except Exception as e:
    if e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'NoSuchEntity':
        print("Entity does not exist")
```

Don't know how much would this help. But this is the approach I took. Cheers!